# Can nanofibers result in the creation of clothes that clean themselves? capabilities?

Tags: nanotechnology

Can a shirt made of nano-fibers have self-cleaning capabilities?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding Aaron! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Your question is a little short and a little vague could you elaborate on it?

Comment: There's too much information missing from your question.  When you say self-cleaning, are you suggesting automation?  Frictionless like Teflon?  Bacteria nullifying like Copper?  We're guessing as to what you're looking for, and that could result in your question being closed.  Please be much more specific about what you're asking so we can have a chance to answer it.

Comment: Welcome *Aaron*! The same I wrote under [your other question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/91187/would-universal-basic-income-work-for-a-galaxy-wide-civilization-like-star-wars) also applies here. Please try to [edit] the question to give us more information about what you already have. Otherwise this might get closed. Though it will first get put on hold to give you a chance of about a week or so to edit the question and get it automatically in the reopen review queue.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes and No,**

Nano-materials could resist nano and larger materials from being caught in it. But might not be able to resist smaller than nano materials from being caught like reactive compounds.

Take for instance that spray you put on objects so water based substances slide right off.
How that works is by spraying on silica particles onto the surface of an object. Those particles work on a molecular level (smaller than nano) to repel water based substances. And even then it can be damaged by a scratch or bond with some other compound.

Alot of this depends on the structure, chemistry, and end composition of the nano-fiber. For instance spider silk is a nano-fiber based substance formed from woven protein chains. Stuff gets caught in that all the time.

**What really matters here is what is your definition of clean?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes and it's already been done. Research into self-cleaning garments has been accomplished. It may not necessary have been nanofibre materials, but it can be achieved.

This has been done with [biofabrication](http://www.wenwang-biofabrication.com/biologic.html) and based on the work of Wen Wang at MIT. Self-cleaning garments are in their infancy. It can be expected that ongoing advances and further in bioenegineering and materials technology that self-cleaning garments will be commonplace.